# TreePanel - navigation treepanel

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

HelIo everyone.

After the second creation, the treapanel does not render the whole tree, why do internal nodes disappear?

Step by Step:
1) Click "Create" Button
2) See "Pages" - Pages has nodes
3) Click "Remove" Button
4) See "Pages" - Pages has not nodes???

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2a05

Comment: Seems like a bug in TreeStore implementation. Once store is created, you can see Ext.getStore('navigationstore').root.data.children . You will find that children is appearing null on first creation itself. Original data should not have been manipulated. Somewhere it gets removed. If you load data with ajax proxy, it should not happen as data will be populated every time and root data will be initialised every time.

Comment: Sorry for my English, but yes, when requested, it will always be generated correctly, but I do not need to load from the server, I need to have a static list worked out